# Custom Google Sheet Function Updating Without Any Cause

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a custom function to pull price data for EVE Online and I would only like the function to update upon a specific cell change. Instead it's updating every ~10-20 minutes which is using up a ton of my daily quota for URL Fetches.

Looking below you can see the main function is in a page labeled "Warehouse Stock". It pulls all price data for items in the "Item" column. The cell refreshes with a custom function that changes cell B4 in the utility sheet. When that cell changes it updates the values in the custom function because of the IF/THEN statement. Lastly the prices are loaded into the main sheet and sorted by the "product" column.

Also I have recalculation "On Change" and Iterative Calculation turned off.

Thank you for reading and any help you can provide.

The custom function is:

```
    /**
* Query's Fuzz market API for the given types
* @param {range} A vertical range of type_ids.
* @return maxBuy and minSell for each type_id
* @customfunction
*/
function fuzzApiPriceData(type_ids) {
  if (!type_ids) throw 'type_ids is required';
  const ids = Array.isArray(type_ids) ? type_ids.map(id => id[0]) : [type_ids];
  const fuzz_price_data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://market.fuzzwork.co.uk/aggregates/?station=60008494&types=${ids.join(',')}`));
  return [['minSell', 'maxBuy']].concat(type_ids.map(type_id => [parseFloat(fuzz_price_data[type_id]['sell']['min']), parseFloat(fuzz_price_data[type_id]['buy']['max'])]));
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try running it from a timebased trigger.

Comment: Tried to use a monthly trigger and it is still doing the same thing. Is there a way to do a "return IF THEN" statement in the custom function so it will only pull the data if it meets a specific criteria such as the cell value in Utility!B4?

Comment: Hi. Could you explain exactly when you want the custom function to recalculate its values? An example would help to understand it. On the other hand, to see why a function has been executed you can see the `Executions` in the left sidebar. There you will see the origin of each execution.

Comment: I would like the function to refresh everyday, aswell as having the option to manually refresh the function by the contents of the cell Utility!B4. I have another function that changes cells B3 and B4 to 0, sleeps for 3 seconds, changes B3 back to 1, sleeps for another 3 seconds, changes B4 back to 1. So the other functions throughout the sheet that us the IF THEN statements are all updated by those 2 cells changing back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

i think there's a fairly basic misunderstanding here.

"Custom functions" are designed to be written in *cells* on a sheet.  they are by there nature designed to run ALL the time, constantly updating.

If you are attempting to run a custom *script*, you do that from the script editor itself, you don't even write the function in a cell *at ALL*.

I'm assuming you didn't write the "custom function" you're using(?)  So it will be a bit difficult (but not impossible!) to convert it to a script that writes to a certain place on the sheet at a certain time.  But you might research a bit more about the difference between custom functions designed to be executed in cells, and scripts designed to be run on a time trigger.

Comment: Ah yeah I have a bunch of custom scripts, one of which changes the contents of the cell when ran. I am only decent at writing scripts, not functions and that is not my function. I basically just want to function written in a way it will not update unless forced

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you answer:

> I would like the function to refresh everyday, aswell as having the option to manually refresh the function by the contents of the cell Utility!B4

I propose you to use [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

1. [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers): It can execute a function each day at specific time.
2. [Installable edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers): It can execute a function when a certain value in a specific cell changes.

However, if you want to execute a function manually, I recommend you to insert a `drawing` and [assign a function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) to it.

### Reference

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do for that is : put a checkbox in a cell. Then, when calling your custom function, add an extra reference to that cell, even if the parameter is not included in your custom function. Each time you will switch true/false, your custom function will be reactivated. Then you can also define another function with a trigger that just change the value of true/false. Here is an example in sheet 'Data' cell A3 : the function is `getDataJSON(C1,A2:U2,A1)` with A1 even if the custom function take into account only the first and second parameter. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DN0Gfim0LC098zVgrUpt2crPWUn4pWfZnCpuuL1ZiMs/edit?usp=sharing